# How to update a bound list of items when changes take place in the DB?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, entity-framework-6

I just noticed that I can't refresh the values fetched from the DB. Storage (i.e. from the client to the DB) works as supposed to. Loading the first time works as charm as well.

However, if someone deletes a row in the DB (say, using SQL Management Studio), that change isn't in effect in my client until I reinstantiate the whole view model. Only calling *Refresh()* doesn't fetch the change. The same goes for altering the values of loaded in records.

However, additions to the table are brought in...

I (re)load the values shown in the view from the DB by calling the following method in the view model.

```
public ViewModel()
{
  Reload();
  ...
}

public void Reload()
{
  _data.Set<Order>().Load();
  _data.Set<TimeFrame>().Load();
  Orders = _data.Set<Order>().Local;
  TimeFrames = _data.Set<TimeFrame>().Local;
  ...
}

readonly Data _data;
private ObservableCollection<Order> _orders;
private ObservableCollection<TimeFrame> _timeFrames;
public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
{
  get { return _orders; }
  set { _orders = value; OnPropertyChanged("Orders"); }
}

public ObservableCollection<TimeFrame> TimeFrames
{
  get { return _timeFrames; }
  set { _timeFrames = value; OnPropertyChanged("TimeFrames"); }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is that you load your values, then you use the local property.

The Local collection contains all the values that have been loaded in your context.
if the first time, you load values (1,2,3,4) your Local collection will contain values (1,2,3,4). The second time you load it, you will perhaps load values (1, 4, 5) your Local collection will contain values (1,2,3,4,5)

you should do something like

```
Orders = new ObservableCollection(_data.Set<Order>());
```

if it is a read only scenario and you don't need to update and save your data, you should even load your data AsNoTracking, so you won't have caching issues and you will have less EF overhead as your entities won't be tracked

```
Orders = new ObservableCollection(_data.Set<Order>().AsNoTracking());
```

Comment: One of those is read-write-delete, the others are read-only, at least for now. Should I skip *Local* at all for the one that is CRUD-able? And modify the others to *AsNoTracking*? Or is that weird to have database of different trackability in the same view model? +1 for good examples.

Comment: If the entities are not modified you can safely use AsNoTracking. Even better, you could make projections and only load the properties that are useful for your view. You can also remove the lines with Load() as they are useless. The data will be loaded in the constructor of your ObservableCollection

Comment: @Konrad Note: if there is a relationship between Order and TimeFrame you could have weird behaviors using AsNoTracking only on one collection. It depends how you use them